# A Colon cannot be used in an unquoted value Error in security.yml

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

i work on symfony project and try to make command `php bin/console server:run` but i get this error:
`A colon cannot be used in an unquoted mapping value at line 33 (near " anonymous:  true").`

The problem become from this file:

[image]

What is wrong with file indentation ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error is in line 25: parameter `pattern` is bad aligned.

Comment: Thank's for your answer, now i have another error `In FileLoader.php : There is no extension able to load configuration for "firewalls".

Comment: firewall should be aligned to same level of encoders.